# Agregar ícono o imagen en ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Tengo un `ListBox` al cual le agrego un `Item` de la siguiente manera

```
//Se agrega el item a la lista 
lBAllTaskGroup.Items.Add(objTask);
lBAllTaskGroup.DisplayMember ="nameTask";
```

Pero necesito agregar un ícono o una imagen en la parte izquierda el Item

Alguna idea?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/z4ka5fex(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Creo que mas sencillo podrias hacerlo con un `list view` un ejemplo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255579/c-sharp-net-windows-forms-listview-with-image-in-detail-view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente debes cambiar el valor de la propiedad `DrawMode` a `OwnerDrawFixed` (si quieres que todos los elementos tengan el mismo tamaño) o `OwnerDrawVariable` (si quieres que éste sea variable).

A partir de ahí deberás definir cómo quieres que se muestre cada elemento en el evento `DrawItem`.

En estos links puedes encontrar algunos ejemplos:

[Personalizar la apariencia de los items de un ListBox](http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/listbox-personalizar-items-windows-forms.html)

[ComboBox con imágenes](http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/combobox-con-imagenes.html)

El segundo ejemplo es exactamente lo que quieres hacer pero el ejemplo está hecho con un ComboBox.